# Do I need to use past tense here?

Tags: tenses

I'm writing a personal statement in which I describe a course I have learned in my college.

Should I use "the course IS really difficult" or "the course WAS really difficult" ?

Since I still think that course is difficult for me, I don't know which tense to use.

Comment: I suggest you should not mention a course you had difficulties with, unless you overcame those difficulties

Answer (score 1):

When you write about something that is no longer going on, then you generally write using the past tense and say something like, "In my sophomore year in university, I **studied** quantum mechanics. The course **was** very difficult, so I **needed** a tutor, but I finally **understood** the basic principles and **scored** 95% on the final examination".

You cannot say that you *learned a course in my college*: it's not native-speaker English, not idiomatic, and not semantically accurate. You may *learn a language*, but you *study* subjects like math, economics, physics, history.

Be careful about what you say and how you say it. You should probably ask a knowledgeable and commonsensical friend to edit your personal statement.

Comment: +1 And in US English, at least, a *course* is  an 'episode', typically a single semester or quarter studying a subject, not a 'course of study' lasting several semesters and comprising several *courses*.

Comment: Yes, look at the tense of all of the verbs around that one and they, generally speaking, should be in the same tense.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are describing your feelings toward a course which you had taken in the past, I believe you should use the past tense.  You opinion carries a context which includes the professor who taught the course, the structure of the course, and your comprehension of the material.  All of these variables are dependent on time.